# Word mail merge: show or hide table

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm creating a mail merge document where I need to hide swathes of the document based on a field I have.  OK.  That's simple enough.  `{IF {MERGEFIELD My_Field} = "True" "a bunch of text ""}`.  But one portion of the document I need to hide contains a table (the table is not dynamic in any way).  However, when I put it inside my merge code, the other text shows up, but not the table.  Is this a limitation of Word, or is it possible to have a table within my conditionally-shown text?

Comment: There is definitely possible to have tables inside IF fields and show conditionally. My first thought as to why it's not working for you is that perhaps you are prematurely ending the IF statment by closing the speech marks ("). If not, could you add your field code to your question?

Comment: I doubt that quotations marks are the issue since text both before and after the table does appear.  However, the table is reduced to a blue dot.

Comment: Tried playing with the table options? Making it inline if it's floating, or perhaps changing the row height rule? Otherwise paste a screenshot of your field code for inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I didn't really figure out what was causing the issue, but I found a good workaround; I split the information into a separate document and then used `{IF {MERGEFIELD My_Field} = "True" "{INCLUDETEXT "C:\\separatefile.docx"}" "" }`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted since it genuinely fixed my problem.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I downvoted this answer as I believe it's a pretty poor work around to have to split your document into two parts. If you continued further you probably could have found the real source of the problem and avoided having to do this.

Comment: But it seems like your suggestions would have required me to change the look of the table, which I didn't want to do.

Comment: Maybe not, it depends on just what was causing the problem. Normally any table should hide and unhide properly when used in an IF table. It would have been interesting to find out what was causing the issue instead of working around it :)